# How to set thread affinity to either performance or efficient cores?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cpu-architecture, affinity

I am familiar with using `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` to set the cpu that a thread would like to run on. In the code below, thread `t` requests to execute on `cpu_target` (set to 13), by setting the affinity mask of `cpuset` via the `CPU_SET` macro.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_t t;
  cpu_set_t cpuset;
  const int cpu_target = 13;
  if (cpu_target >= get_nprocs_conf())
    return -1;

  CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
  CPU_SET(cpu_target, &cpuset);
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
  pthread_create(&t, &attr, [](void*) -> void* { return nullptr; }, nullptr);

  pthread_join(t, nullptr);
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  return 0;
}
```

We can enquire as to how many cores are available. If there are `N` cores available, we can set the affinity mask of each thread to run on a core from `0` to `N-1`.

Many processors now have performance and efficient cores. For example, the i9-14900K has 24 cores (8 performance and 16 efficient Cores); with the 8 performance cores each able to run 2 hyperthreads.

How can I configure thread affinity for either a performance core; or an efficiency core?

Comment: In general you should be able to let the os figure this out (at least new processors have a lot of logic to do this for you).  But there already seems to be an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645880/set-cpu-affinity-when-create-a-thread which refers to (https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/).  In general in C++ just use std::thread as much as you can (and forget pthreads exist)

Comment: This is basically a POSIX question. I guess you should expect to find answers in C. So the tags need a fix, because no C++ specific features are present in question, nor - I guess - in the answers to come.

Comment: @Red.Wave: C and C++ are different languages, neither is a subset of the other.  e.g. C++ is missing VLAs and doesn't allow implicit conversion from `void*`.  This is tagged [c++], so it's a C++ question.  It does happen to be using the C-like subset of C++, though, which is usually poor style.  I'd have used `std::thread` even if I was going to use pthread affinity functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't remember using the term **subset**. **pthread** being a POSIX C API, means what the OP asks is another set of functions within the same API. I guess it's clear that C++ std doesn't support cpu affinity or any thread customization. Any 3rd party C++ library would naturally wrap platform specific C API functions: Thus, if the OP is answerable, there must be some pthread function in the C API, which will again be a C language related answer. If everything is going C, then so shall the tag. This notifies the C community to answer; because in this matter, they know better.

Comment: If it were a POSIX question in the exclusive sense you seem to mean, @Red.Wave, then would that not imply that one should expect to find answers in *POSIX*?  But in fact, `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` is not a POSIX function (that's what the `_np` signifies), and neither C nor POSIX (nor C++) has any standard features that would provide for a program to distinguish among execution units with different characteristics.

Comment: @JohnBollinger then it is even more domain specific and limited to some Linux distro, which is even less C++ freindly. Again the linux OS API is primarily in C. Everything else is a binding. And I guess there's no C++ binding for this one. This proves that the question belongs to C and not C++. I wish it could have a C++ specific answer; But I'm afraid it cannot.

Comment: I added the C++ tag as I have used a lambda function (although surprisingly my C compilers also run this code). I know that I can use `std::thread::native_handle` and `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` with a `std::thread`, but at this point it is the central question of selecting either a performance or an efficient core that I am focused on. (I've nevertheless now added the C tag.) I will happily accept a method involving any POSIX, UNIX, or other library - potentially even a closed source library.

Comment: This doesn't compile as C: https://godbolt.org/z/vvW86cq69 shows GCC rejecting the lambda.  Perhaps you ran `gcc foo.cpp`?  The `gcc` front-end detects the language as C++ because of the filename and compiles accordingly, but still only links the C standard library, not the C++ library.  Since you don't use any C++ library functions like `std::cout <<`, it will happen to work.  (BTW, I had to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and `#include <sched.h>` in C mode but not C++ to get definitions for the Linux macrs like `CPU_SET`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure thread affinity for either a performance core; or an efficiency core?

There is no standard interface defined by C,  C++, or POSIX for distinguishing among execution units with different characteristics.  In fact, `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np()` itself is a non-standard GNU extension.<sup>*</sup>  Other environments may provide similar interfaces, but at the level of generality of the question -- that is, without specifying a particular environment -- the main answer is that there is no standard way to control on which execution units your programs run.

A secondary answer is that for the most part, *you shouldn't need to do*.  A key enabling technology for the kind of CPU design you're talking about is built-in logic for automatically making good choices about on which cores any given thread should run.  Looking forward, it's also reasonable to expect that compilers will soon get better at generating code that helps such CPUs do a good job of that, and that operating system kernels will soon learn how to use such CPUs to the best advantage. Only if you have very special needs might it make sense to invest time and money into the kind of manual core-affinity management you describe.

**But if you do have such needs**, and if we can safely conclude from your Glibc dependency that you're looking for a Linux-specific solution, then that would probably be to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` to determine the characteristics of the system's CPU cores.  Then use that information to choose which cores to set affinity for.

---

<sup>*</sup> The same for related function [sched_setaffinity()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html).

Comment: The main use-case I can think of for pinning to E cores or P cores would be for microbenchmarking, so you can measure separately for the two types of cores.  Or perhaps to make sure P cores aren't already occupied when some latency-sensitive task wakes up.  Maybe even to run some background SETI@home type of workload only on E-cores even when there are spare P-cores, to optimize for energy efficiency not performance.  (I think your answer is a good balance of actually answering the question without demanding that it justify its existence, while still pointing out that you normally shouldn't.)