# How to create a generic C++ class that takes in method of another class and runs it at given interval in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling

My knowledge of C++ is basic and would appreciate some help in architecting my code in a scalable way. I have couple of classes with following general format

```
class Class1{
    public:
        Class1();
        ~Class1();
        run();
    private:
        var1;
        var2;
          .
          .

};

class Class2{
    public:
        Class2();
        ~Class2();
        run(args1, args2);
    private:
        var1;
        var2;
          .
          .

};

class Class3{
    public:
        Class3();
        ~Class3();
        run(args1);
    private:
        var1;
        var2;
          .
          .

};
```

Now I would like to create a generic C++ class which takes in a function handle from above classes, spawns a thread, sets CPU affinity, sets sched_priority and runs that function at an user provided interval. So something like below

```
class GenericScheduler{
    public:
        GenericScheduler();
        ~GenericScheduler(Stop the thread and clean up);
        CreateAndRun(function, interval, cpu_2_use, sched_priority){
            Step1. Create a new thread
            Step2. Set the new thread to run on **cpu_2_use** at **sched_priority** level
            Step3. Run the **function** in a loop indefinitely at the provided **interval**
        }
 
};
```

Then the `main` would look like below

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    Class1 Class1Task;
    Class2 Class2Task;
    Class3 Class3Task;
    
    GenericScheduler scheduler1;
    GenericScheduler scheduler2;
    GenericScheduler scheduler3;

    scheduler1.CreateAndRun(Class1Task.run(), 10ms, cpu = 1, sched_priority = 5);
    scheduler2.CreateAndRun(Class2Task.run(args1, args2), 20ms, cpu = 2, sched_priority = 10);
    scheduler3.CreateAndRun(Class3Task.run(args1), 5ms, cpu = 1, sched_priority = 20);
}
```

Is it possible to have this kind of flexibility? Also as a follow up question can we do this with only one GenericScheduler object instead of 3 (that is instead of using scheduler1, scheduler2, scheduler3 only use one scheduler)? Looking forward to what people suggest because I can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) comes to mind.

Comment: As for the affinity and priority, that's not available through [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). You have to get the native handle and use OS-specific functions for that.

Comment: And infinite threads only makes sense if you detach them. I still recommend some way of nicely shutting them down anyway, to avoid problems in thread termination (like what could happen if a thread does some important work and are just killed in the middle).

Comment: Also, I hope you don't have too many timers like that. You should look into pooling threads, to share resources so it's not too much work for each core, where you risk having the OS and the cores spend more time scheduling threads than actually running them.

Comment: Lastly, high-precision timers aren't really available on generic operating systems. Even five milliseconds might be a tight squeeze some times. And I really hope you're planning to use the OS-native timers, rather than just putting the threads to sleep for an interval. Because that will be even worse.

Comment: *"which takes in a function handle"* -- What do you consider to be a "handle" for a function? A pointer to the function? Or something more generic? Do you really care what it takes in? Over-specifying your requirements can rule out otherwise good solutions. Do you really mean "which takes in something to execute"?

Comment: @JaMiT yeah "which takes in something to execute" is totally a valid solution to my problem. What can help with that implementation?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using the following in Raspberry Pi to set CPU affinity

`
// Variables to set CPU affinity
 cpu_set_t cpuset;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
  CPU_SET(3, &cpuset);

 pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
 sch.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
 pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &sch);
 int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(),
                                    sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);    
 if (rc != 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error calling pthread_setaffinity_np on main(): " << rc << "\n";
    }
`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also so far I have been using hires timer in c++

Comment: If you mean `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, then please be careful. On some systems it might just be an alias for `std::chrono::system_clock`. So not that "high resolution". And could change as the system clock changes (think daylight savings, etc.). If you don't want to use the Linux (I assume) timers then use `std::chrono::steady_clock` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate to one of the questions being asked: [Set CPU affinity when create a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24645880) *(I didn't find a dupe for the question of how to create a thread. I did not look for a duplicate of the question about writing a loop, nor for the one about scheduling on an interval. Too many questions per post.)*

Comment: @JaMiT more so than setting CPU affinity I am looking for a way to spin out threads with tasks that run at specific interval. Being able to set CPU affinity is a nice to have but not necessary.

Comment: To call a non-static member function of a class, you need TWO bits of information - an object, and a (pointer to) a member function to call on that object via something like `some_object.some_member()`.   If the function accepts arguments, you need the arguments to pass too.   The  `std::function` (function wrapper) is a typical way of achieving that.

Comment: @user3746381 *"more so than [one question] I am looking for [another question]"* -- This is a reason to focus on one question per question. Keep questions focused on one issue, similar to how functions should be focused on one task.

Comment: I guess I got the answer I needed so nothing wrong with the question I asked. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @user3746381 *"I got the answer I needed so nothing wrong with the question I asked."* -- That is an invalid conclusion. (I mean that in the strictly logical sense. I am not here claiming that the conclusion is wrong, only that it does not follow from the stated premise.) The purpose of this site is to provide a library of questions and answers for the future; the benefit to the person asking is secondary.

Comment: @JaMiT I politely disagree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of scheduler skeleton code I would write. To create the loop timeout never use sleep, condition variables are great to get more responsive code.

Demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/Q48nmDbdj

Use `m_thread_ptr->native_handle();` to get the native handle of the thread to be able use OS specicific calls (pthread/winapi) to change thread priorities etc.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class scheduler_t
{
public:

    // In multithreading context always take extra care to
    // shutdown nicely e.g. cooperatively
    ~scheduler_t()
    {
        if (m_thread_ptr != nullptr)
        {
            set_thread_state(thread_state_v::stopping); // signal workerthread to finish
            wait_for_thread_state(thread_state_v::stopped); 
            m_thread_ptr->join(); // join for correct shutdown without race conditions
        }
    }

    template<typename fn_t>
    void schedule_and_run(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration interval, fn_t fn) // TODO thread priority etc...
    {
        m_thread_ptr = std::make_unique<std::thread>([=]
        {
            set_thread_state(thread_state_v::running);

            while (true)
            {
                fn();

                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_mtx};
                // Use condition variables wait with timeout to
                // have a "sleep" that can respond immediately on shutdown
                if (m_cv.wait_for(lock, interval, [this] { return m_state == thread_state_v::stopping; }))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            set_thread_state(thread_state_v::stopped);
        });

        // do not return until scheduled thread has really started running
        // avoids some race conditions in more complex code
        wait_for_thread_state(thread_state_v::running);
    }

private:

    // from this codes point of view the scheduled thread has some states 
    enum class thread_state_v { idle, running, stopping, stopped };

    // allow for inter-thread synchronization based on state of the worker thread
    void set_thread_state(thread_state_v state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_mtx};
        m_state = state;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_for_thread_state(thread_state_v state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_mtx};
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&] { return m_state == state; });
    }

    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    thread_state_v m_state{ thread_state_v::idle };
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread_ptr;
};


int main()
{
    scheduler_t scheduler;
    scheduler.schedule_and_run(100ms, [] {std::cout << "."; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact type of example I was looking for. This is a great starting point for. I really appreciate your help.